# HighChart generating table without chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is code    `jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/`    which generate both chart and table, but I need only highchart table. How I can implement it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by removing the series from the chart object and only using it for rendering the table:

```
// internal variables
var chart = this,
    series =[{
     name: 'Tokyo',
     data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
  }, {
     name: 'New York',
     data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
  }, {
     name: 'Berlin',
     data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
  }, {
     name: 'London',
     data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  }],
```

You also need to change the position of the table:

```
var tableTop = 30,
```

and finally make the div smaller:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px;margin-top:20px;width: 600px"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvgnq84v/

Comment: But table is filled with zeros. Why?

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me want did you change? I can not understand why previous code didn't work

Comment: I change renderer.text(
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix,  to renderer.text(
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(point, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix,